# ftell errors on really large files

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit

According to the unix man pages `ftell` either returns -1 to indicate an error.

The function definition is:

```
long int ftell ( FILE * stream );
```

Where `long int` is a 32 bit integer (you need `long long` for 64 bit)

however `(-1L) == 0x00000000FFFFFFFF LL` which should be a valid value for really large files (round about 4GB) in which case, how do we know whether an error has occurred or we just have a really large file?

Comment: You could check `errno` or switch to `off64_t ftello64(FILE *stream)`. Encountering a file which is >2^63 in bytes is at least less possible than one having >2^31 bytes.

Comment: @Neet put your comment down as an answer.

Comment: "Where long int is a 32 bit integer" - I guess **no.** Nothing guarantees/requires that. On any sensible 64-bit implementation, it's in fact 64 bits long. (You read that right -- Windows does not count as a "sensible implementation".)

Comment: Please tell me on what platform long in is 64 bit. I know of none.

Comment: @doron Ever heard of Linux? OS X? iOS (recently)?

Comment: @user529758, On a Window machine, `printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof (long));` can readily print 8, even for some years now.  The OS does not set the size of `long`, the compiler does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either check `errno` or use the 64 bit version of `ftell` called `off64_t ftello64(FILE *stream)`.